# White screen displays when I deploy react project

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, mobx, chakra-ui

I have a react project and it is working properly but when I deploy it I am seeing a white screen. I am using react-router v6 in the project.
I attempted to address the white screen issue but were unable to resolve it.

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: Pages.SMARTFUNDLIST,
      element: <MainLayout web3={web3} accounts={accounts} network={network} isLoadNetID={isLoadNetID} />,
      loader: rootloader,
      children: [
        {
          path: Pages.SMARTFUNDLIST,
          element: <SmartFundList {...props} web3={web3} accounts={accounts} isDataLoad={isDataLoad} setIsDataLoad={setIsDataLoad} />,
          loader: smartfundloader,
        },
        {
          path: Pages.SMARTFUNDLISTWITHOUTWEB3,
          element: <SmartFundListWithoutWeb3 {...props} web3={web3} isDataLoad={isDataLoad} setIsDataLoad={setIsDataLoad} />,
          loader: smartfundwithoutloader
        },
        {
          path: Pages.VIEWFUNDWITHOUTWEB3,
          element: <ViewFundWithoutWeb3 {...props} web3={web3} accounts={accounts} />,
          loader: fundinfoloader
        },
        {
          path: Pages.VIEWFUNDTX,
          element: <ViewFundTx {...props} isDataLoad={isDataLoad} />,
          loader: viewfunttxloader
        },
        {
          path: Pages.VIEWUSERTX,
          element: <ViewUserTx {...props} isDataLoad={isDataLoad} />,
          loader: viewusertxloader
        },
        {
          path: Pages.VIEWFUND,
          element: <ViewFund {...props} web3={web3} accounts={accounts} MobXStorage={props.MobXStorage} />,
          loader: viewfundloader
        },
        {
          path: Pages.VIEWUSER,
          element: <ViewUser {...props} />,
          loader: viewuserloader
        },
        {
          path: Pages.HOWTOSTART,
          element: <HowToStart {...props} />,
          loader: howtostartloader
        }
      ]
    },
```